# How to add a + sign at the start of number which should be non editable and passed along with number?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have mobile number textbox I have to add + at the start of the mobile number which should be non-editable and should with send with other value to api.

HTML

<input type="number" (input)="leadingPlus($event)" [(ngModel)]="setValues.mobile" />

TS

```
leadingPlus(input) {
    console.log(input.target.value)
    if (!isNaN(input.target.value) && input.target.value.length === 1) {
      input.target.value = '+' + input.target.value;
    }
    this.mobile = input.target.value;
  }
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: hard code the '+' in your HTML file, and add the '+' sign when you save the phone number to your **this.mobile** variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution for you is to display the "+" next to the input for the user. And then add it programmatically to the wanted variable when you save the value of the input.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make two boxes with the + in the one with not editable or you could use

```
input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  if(e.target.value.startsWith('+') == false)
     e.target.value = "+" + e.target.value
}
```